# How to select multiple rows of KendoUI Grid for Angular 4+ and move it to another kendoUI Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I have 2 Kendo Grids(angular 4+ component) where data is coming from Rest API.
I have to select and move the data row from the first grid to another grid. For example i am bindind the grid like this:

```html
<div>
            <kendo-grid [height]="450"
                        [kendoGridBinding]="viewAvailableJobs"
                        [scrollable]="scrollable"
                        [selectable]="true"                           
                        (selectionChange)="gridUserSelectionChange($event)">
              <kendo-grid-column field="Select" width="30" [locked]="true" [filterable]="false">
                <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>
                  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="false" />
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="Select {{dataItem.JobNumber}}" value="Selected" name="cSelection-{{dataItem.JobNumber}}"
                         [checked]="Selected"
                         (change)="onCheckboxChange($event, dataItem, 'select')"
                         (clicked)="setButtonStateS()" />
                </ng-template>
              </kendo-grid-column>

              <kendo-grid-column field="JobNumber" title="Job #" [width]="150" [locked]="true">
              </kendo-grid-column>
              <kendo-grid-column field="jobName" title="Job Name" [width]="320" [locked]="true">
              </kendo-grid-column>
              <kendo-grid-column field="jobStatusUID" title="Job Status" [width]="150" [locked]="true">
              </kendo-grid-column>             
              <kendo-grid-column field="ProjectNumber" title="Project" [width]="150">
              </kendo-grid-column>
              <kendo-grid-column field="scheduleNumber" title="Schedule" [width]="150">
              </kendo-grid-column>
              <kendo-grid-column field="oeName" title="POE" [width]="220">
              </kendo-grid-column>
            
            </kendo-grid>
</div>
```

The other grid 2 also has some data, i will have to add or also have to append the data(if there is already some existing data) to grid datasource. I am binding through service, rest api like this:

```js
constructor(private JobService: DataService){}
public ngOnInit(): void { 
     this.JobService.getAvailableJobs(this.projectstr, this.programstr).subscribe(req => {
                    this.viewAvailableJobs = req;
                    this.totalAvailableJobs = req.length;                    
                });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To Answer StepUp:

```
public selectedrowsArray = new Array;
private Selection = [{ label: 'Selected', state: false }];
onCheckboxChange(e, dataItem, type, rindex1) {

    if (e.target.checked) {
            this.selectedrowsArray .push(dataItem);
    }
    else if (e.target.checked == false) {
   this.selectedrowsArray .splice(this.selectedrowsArray.indexOf(dataItem), 1);

    }
```

In your kendoGrid  There should be a checkbox change event
like this:

```
(change)="onCheckboxChangeEvent($event, dataItem,rowIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just answering if someone else comes looking for an answer:
You can do that by manipulating the grid data source array.
Use array Splice method to extract the rows from array in Grid 1 and generate a new array. Push that new generated array to Grid 2 data source. 
Also, my grid was not refreshing as soon as i was manipulating the array data source, so i had to remove paging from kendo grid and it worked.

Comment: How  do you get selected rows to splice them into new array?

Comment: @StepUp Answered you in the Post Hope that helps.